# What the type of distribution may mean?

Tags: distributions, modeling, distribution-identification

Some time ago I crossed paths with a textbook that had a whole back chapter on this subject. I loaned it to a co-worker and it went missing. The book was for modeling and simulation people who were trying to use a distribution as an engine for various randomized events. For example if you wanted a process to occur regularly with a fixed period, but there would be some fluctuation, that is a normal distribution. If you wanted to work toward some minimum time goal the distribution skewed heavily toward that minimum value with a long tail off into longer times. The idea was that I can select a random value on [0,1) and then use that as a seed within the distribution function to get the distribution value which matches my random variable.

That chapter was full of phrases like "the Gaussian distribution indicates a process that has strong quality control tolerances around the central mean. For example the exact length of a soda straw may vary by only +/-.1 mm. Use μ for the desired value and σ/6=% of deviation."

I'm looking for something that reflects that sort of specificity in setting up the distributions. Does anyone know what this is called or where I can find it?

Comment: The JBStatistics YouTube channel does something like this for a bunch of distributions.

Comment: You **might** look into maxent (maximum entropy)